# How to test Internet connection on multiple network interfaces

Tags: delphi, networking, connection

I have to prepare small program in Delphi that installed on PCs (running WinXP, Win7) in office would be sending to MySQL database info about Internet connection.
So far it is working fine. But there are some computers with multiple network interfaces (either 2 network cards or virtual cards) and program should detect if connection is available on either (and not "in general" as it is now).

How to test in this situation if there is Internet connection?

Comment: What are you going to do with the information? Does your db client layer allow you to select a specific interface? Is it possible that you have got the wrong solution to whatever your problem is?

Comment: I have solution for checking online status on device itself. But I need to know if I can connect via interface A with internet and with interface B only with local network. I don't really know when to start with it.
How it should work? Delphi app that runs on PCs checks if there is Internet connectivity on any interface and saves it's status do DB.
Sorry for my poor english if I didn't explain it clear.

Comment: I cannot understand that. You did not answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the available interfaces using `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.  For any given interface IP address, create a TCP socket, `bind()` it to the IP, `connect()` it to any known good server on the Internet, and check the result.  Repeat for each interface as needed.